# Bulk collect with cursor in postgres 11.2

Tags: postgresql

I am migrating from Oracle to postgresql. I use bulk collect with cursor in Oracle. How do I achieve the same in postgres. I tried with insert into.. select from. It doesnt work.I am newbie to postgres. I have the next code in Oracle.

```
PROCEDURE DEAL_CONVRSNL(ERR_CODE OUT NUMBER, DEAL_ERR OUT VARCHAR2) IS

V_DLHSTDT     ITMDEALEXT.IDLDEALSTDT%TYPE;
v_count     number(1);

CURSOR CUR_GET_DLHHDR IS select .... GROUP BY DLHVALUE

TYPE TYP_GET_DLHHDR IS TABLE OF CUR_GET_DLHHDR%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
REC_GET_DLHHDR TYP_GET_DLHHDR;

BEGIN

OPEN CUR_GET_DLHHDR;
LOOP
  FETCH CUR_GET_DLHHDR BULK COLLECT
    INTO REC_GET_DLHHDR LIMIT 1500;

  FOR I IN 1 .. REC_GET_DLHHDR.COUNT LOOP
      V_IDLDEALTYPE := REC_GET_DLHHDR(I).DLHTYPE;

begin
      SELECT COUNT(1)
        into v_count
        FROM dlhhdr
       where dlhextno = V_DLHEXTNO

  BEGIN
       IF v_count = 0 THEN

         INSERT INTO DLHHDR DLHVALUE VALUES REC_GET_DLHHDR(I).DLHVALUE
    else
         UPDATE DLHHDR
           SET DLHVALUE    = REC_GET_DLHHDR(I).DLHVALUE,
```

I tried with array_agg. Got stuck with for each in using array_agg. What is the equivalent of this in postgres?

Comment: The code isn't even complete but looks like an extremely convoluted and slow way of doing a MERGE. Do you have a unique index on `dlhhdr.dhlextno`?  Then you can replace the whole thing with a single `insert into .. select ..  on conflict do update`

Comment: I have not mentioed the complete code. yes its unique key.

Comment: How can I mention cursor with bulk collect in postgresql. Please help.

Comment: You can't and you usually don't have to. The whole procedure can be replaced with a single statement. There is no need for this in Postgres.

Comment: Thanks. How about procedure with update and insert with cursor. If you could show some samples would be really helpful. Please check the below post.                                     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62256951/bulk-collect-with-cursor-in-postgres