# Bulk collect with cursor in postgres

Tags: postgresql

We are migrating from Oracle to Postgres. I have the next code. I am stuck with bulk collect cursor. I tried using insert into .. select * from.. But as this code check with some particular column, I am confused.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION usmqa.pk_vpdata_load_load_vdrarmhlink(
    OUT err_code bigint,
    OUT vdrarmhlink_errmsg text)
    RETURNS record
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    
AS $BODY$
DECLARE

V_COUNT_VDRARMHLINK bigint;

CUR_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK CURSOR FOR
  SELECT VENLINKID,
         VENARINTNO,
         VENMVINTNO,
         VENLINKEFFDT,
         VENLINKTRMDT,
         VENACT,
         VENRUNSTS,
         VENPROCID,
         VENERRCODE
    FROM INT_VDRARMHLINK
   WHERE VENRUNSTS = -1
     AND coalesce(VENERRMSG::text, '') = ''
     AND coalesce(VENERRCODE::text, '') = '';

        -- TYPE TYP_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK IS TABLE OF RECORD INDEX BY integer;    Oracle code
       --REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK TYP_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK;    --- Oracle 
     REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK int[];
      I int;

BEGIN

glo_error_var:= 0;
UPDATE INT_VDRARMHLINK SET VENRUNSTS = -1 WHERE VENRUNSTS = 0;


glo_error_var:= 1;
UPDATE INT_VDRARMHLINK
   SET VENERRMSG  = 'VENDOR INTERNAL NUMBER DOES NOT EXISTS VDREXT TABLE',
       VENERRCODE = -1,
       VENRUNSTS  = -2
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM VDREXT WHERE VDXINTNO = VENARINTNO)
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM VDREXT WHERE VDXINTNO = VENMVINTNO);
COMMIT;


  glo_error_var:= 2;
OPEN CUR_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK;
LOOP
 -- FETCH CUR_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK BULK COLLECT ---- Oracle code
   -- INTO REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK LIMIT 1000; ---- Oracle code

 -- FOR I IN 1 .. REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK.COUNT LOOP   -- Oracle code 
 
SELECT arrat_agg(CUR_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK)
into REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK
FROM CUR_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK;

FOREACH I SLICE 1 in ARRAY REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK
LOOP

    BEGIN
      SELECT COUNT(1)
        INTO STRICT V_COUNT_VDRARMHLINK
        FROM VDRARMHLINK
       WHERE  VENARINTNO = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I].VENARINTNO
         AND VENMVINTNO = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I].VENMVINTNO;
    END;

    --INSERT
    IF ( V_COUNT_VDRARMHLINK = 0 AND
        REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I].VENRUNSTS = -1) THEN


    SELECT VENLINKID,
         VENARINTNO,
         VENMVINTNO,
         VENLINKEFFDT,
         VENLINKTRMDT,
         VENACT,
         VENRUNSTS,
         VENPROCID,
         VENERRCODE
    FROM INT_VDRARMHLINK
   WHERE VENRUNSTS = -1
     AND coalesce(VENERRMSG::text, '') = ''
     AND coalesce(VENERRCODE::text, '') = '';
     
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO VDRARMHLINK
        (VENLINKID,
           VENARINTNO,
           VENMVINTNO,
           VENLINKEFFDT,
           VENLINKTRMDT)        
        VALUES (REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I].VENLINKID,
           REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I].VENARINTNO,
           REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I].VENMVINTNO,
           REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I].VENLINKEFFDT,
           REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I].VENLINKTRMDT);

        UPDATE INT_VDRARMHLINK
           SET VENRUNSTS = 1
         WHERE 
        VENPROCID = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I].VENPROCID
           AND VENERRCODE = NULL
           AND VENERRMSG = NULL;

      END;

    END IF;
    
    
    IF (V_COUNT_VDRARMHLINK = 1) THEN

      BEGIN

        UPDATE VDRARMHLINK
           SET VENLINKEFFDT = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I].VENLINKEFFDT,
               VENLINKTRMDT = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I].VENLINKTRMDT
         WHERE VENLINKID = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I].VENLINKID
           AND VENARINTNO = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I].VENARINTNO
           AND VENMVINTNO = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I].VENMVINTNO;

        UPDATE INT_VDRARMHLINK
           SET VENRUNSTS = 1
         WHERE  VENPROCID = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I]
        .VENPROCID
           AND VENLINKID = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I]
        .VENLINKID
           AND VENARINTNO = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I]
        .VENARINTNO
           AND VENMVINTNO = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I]
        .VENMVINTNO
           AND VENERRCODE = NULL
           AND VENERRMSG = NULL;

      END;

    END IF;

    --DELETE
    IF (REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I].VENACT = 2 AND V_COUNT_VDRARMHLINK = 1) THEN

      BEGIN

        UPDATE VDRARMHLINK
           SET VENLINKEFFDT = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I].VENLINKEFFDT,
               VENLINKTRMDT = clock_timestamp()
         WHERE VENLINKID = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I]
        .VENLINKID
           AND VENARINTNO = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I]
        .VENARINTNO
           AND VENMVINTNO = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I].VENMVINTNO;

        UPDATE INT_VDRARMHLINK
           SET VENRUNSTS = 1
         WHERE VENACT = 2
           AND VENPROCID = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I]
        .VENPROCID
           AND VENLINKID = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I]
        .VENLINKID
           AND VENARINTNO = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I]
        .VENARINTNO
           AND VENMVINTNO = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I]
        .VENMVINTNO
           AND VENERRCODE = NULL
           AND VENERRMSG = NULL;

      
    ELSIF (REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I]
          .VENACT = 2 AND V_COUNT_VDRARMHLINK = 0) THEN

      UPDATE INT_VDRARMHLINK
         SET VENRUNSTS  = -3,
             VENERRCODE = -300,
             VENERRMSG  = 'THERE IS NO VENODR AR MERCHANDISE IN VP TO DELETE'
       WHERE VENACT = 2
         AND VENPROCID = REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK[I]
      .VENPROCID
         AND VENERRCODE = NULL
         AND VENERRMSG = NULL;
    END IF;

   
  END LOOP;
  EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND; /* apply on CUR_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK */
END LOOP;
CLOSE CUR_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK;

   END;

   $BODY$;
```

Comment: Just don't do bulk collect, iterate the results row by row.

Comment: Thanks. Should I use array_agg to hold the cursor value??

Comment: Which part of your long code sample are you alluding to?

Comment: Those update statements after 'IF (V_COUNT_VDRARMHLINK = 1) THEN'

Comment: No, you don't use arrays at all. You process the query results one by one.

Comment: Thanks. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING         . Can I refer this. Sry for too many question. I am newbie to postgres.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Although PL/PGSQL has cursors similar to Oracle PL/SQL, there is no BULK COLLECT statement in PL/PGSQL.

When porting Oracle PL/SQL code to PostgreSQL PL/PGSQL code, see [Porting from Oracle PL/SQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-porting.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT arrat_agg(CUR_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK)
into REC_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK
FROM CUR_GET_INT_VDRARMHLINK;
```

Did these work for you?